# How to add double \ to a string if it contains brackets (AppleScript)

Tags: shell, terminal, applescript

I have written an AppleScript which gets lyrics from Genius and adds it to my iTunes songs.

Essentially there is a loop which goes through my songs which have been recently added to iTunes, for each song it then goes to genius and tried to find that song, if it can't find the song then the `song_name` and `song_artist` are put into a variable called `songNotAva`. The way it is put inside the variable is:
`set songNotAva to songNotAva & {"- ", song_name, " - ", song_artist & return}`.
And then once the loop to "get all the lyrics for songs" is finished, if `songNotAva` is not empty, then it executes this code:

```
if songNotAva is not equal to {} then
    do shell script "> $HOME/Desktop/songs.txt"
    do shell script "echo " & songNotAva & ">> $HOME/Desktop/songs.txt"
end if
```

which outputs the failed songs into a text file with this format:

```
- song_name - song_artist
- song_name - song_artist
- song_name - song_artist
```

(The `song_name` and `song_artist` will reflect the song that failed)

It works perfectly fine and outputs exactly how I expect it to, but the problem is that some of the song titles in iTunes contain brackets (), and if you try to output those brackets using the shell, it will come up with an error and won't output anything (unless you have backslashes before the brackets like \\(\\)  then it will work fine)

so, all the songs which can't be found are saved in the list `songNotAva` and are later printed out to the text file once the loop has finished.

My question is how can I check if the song_title contains any brackets, and if it does then how can I add the backslash before the brackets?

Comment: perhaps try `& quoted form of songNotAva &` ?

Comment: @jhnc I get an error saying “Can’t make quoted form of {“7 rings(example bracket)”} into type Unicode text.”

Comment: Is `songNotAva` meant to be a list? If so, I guess you'll need to loop over each element (unless you want to echo everything to a single line of `songs.txt`)

Comment: @jhnc Yes, it is meant to be a list. Essentially the way it works is that for every song where the lyrics couldn't be found, it is added to that variable, and then once the loop (to get lyrics) is finished, if `songNotAva` is not empty, then make a text file and then fill it with the songs that failed using the format `- song name - song artist` on each new line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`songNotAva` is a list, you have to use a loop and escape each string with `quoted form of`.

A check for empty list is redundant. If the list is empty the loop will be skipped.

```
set songNotAva to {"7 rings(example bracket)"}

do shell script "> $HOME/Desktop/songs.txt"
repeat with aSong in songNotAva
    do shell script "echo " & quoted form of aSong & " >> $HOME/Desktop/songs.txt"
end repeat
```

Comment: That's great! It outputs without any error.
This outputs everything in the list on a new line, if you look at my original post (I have updated it), the format of my list would be `- song name - song artist` and this would be the same on every line (but with updated name and artist). So is there a way to print all of that on one line for each song?

Comment: Sorry, I don't see the relationship between `{"7 rings(example bracket)"}` and  `{"- ", song_name, " - ", song_artist & return}`. Please edit the question to provide a comprehensible example of input and output.

Comment: sorry about that, I have updated the whole question so it's hopefully a lot easier to understand.

Your fix works for the bracket problem (thanks for that), but it prints everything in the list on a new line, I want to print it in the format shown above.

Comment: I still don't understand, sorry.